# Create a dictionary of objects with variable names for keys like NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

On iOS with Objective-C there's a really handy macro that fills a dictionary with key value pairs of variable names and variables automatically called NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings:

```
 NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1, v2, v3);
```

which is equivalent to

```
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:v1, @“v1”, v2, @“v2”, v3, @“v3”, nil];;
```

Does anyone know of a similar technique in C#?  Ideally I'd want to create an extension method like

```
 Dictionary.FromVariableBindings(v1, v2, v3);
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
 new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
       {"v1", v1},
       {"v2", v2},
       {"v3", v3}
 }
```

This would be really helpful for use with Xamarin / MonoTouch.

Comment: What is your key value pair input?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording, I'm thinking the LINQ extension method `ToDictionary` will work for you, but that works best if you are wanting to create a new dictionary instance. What I want/need to know is if the key-value-pairs are going to be added in bulk or one at a time.

Comment: They're not pairs, just variables. The names of the variables from the source code should end up as the keys with the variables themselves as the values.  I don't even know if this is possible in C#.

Comment: You will be pleasantly surprised then. Use reflection to get the names and values. This can be done practically anywhere that has access to the fields/properties in question.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with local variables not fields/properties.  I guess my example wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you want you want.  It's a one liner using linq.

```
var objects = new object[] { 1, "Hello", 1.0M }; //Just create some system objects to show that it works.
var result = objects.ToDictionary(o => o.GetType().Name);
```

If you want it to look like the same signature as IOS then you could do something like this.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> FromVariableBindings(params object[] objects)
{
    return objects.ToDictionary(o => o.GetType().Name);
}
```

In reading he question again you might be looking for the variable names rather the the object types.  If that is the case it becomes much more difficult.  You can call the code below to get the variable name but it won't work right in a foreach loop.

```
var temp = 1;

var result = GetMemberName(() => temp); //returns "temp"





public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
        return expressionBody.Member.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Yes this GetMemberName attempt is closer to what I'm trying to do, still not quite clear to me how to use it with a convenient syntax though.